# Using holo light colors in android Lower API

Tags: android, colors

The problem is that when I am using Holo theme colors for my app I am getting error that `@android:color/ holo_bright_ blue` requires higherAPI. I am using appcompat for my app. Any way to use holo theme colors in lower API?

Comment: use `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: I am using `Thme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` . see if suppose i have a textview and i want it to be of `@android:color/ holo_bright_ blue` this color then I am getting an error

Comment: it available above api level 14 i guess. Use a custom color instead.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#holo_blue_light

Comment: Have you tried holo everywhere library?

Comment: No I havent @user1685095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an approximation of the color instead of using the android reference.  For instance, holo_blue_bright is fairly close to **#31B6E7**

Comment: You can get the exact color codes at the developer site: http://developer.android.com/design/style/color.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [HoloEveryWhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) library, that brings holo widgets and themes to the <4.0 devices.

I don't know if this would help you with your specific question, but it probably should.